# Duplicated X509Certificate

Tags: c#, xml, digital-signature, x509certificate, sign

I am trying to sign an XML file and for some reason its adding two `<X509Certificate>` tags under `<X509Data>` tag.
Values in  tags are not identical. (see example below)

```
<KeyInfo>
  <X509Data>
    <X509Certificate>KJASHDJASHAHDJA</X509Certificate>
    <X509Certificate>ASJKLDJASDJASDJKLASJDASJKDASA</X509Certificate>
  </X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
```

This is happening after i had to change old certificate after it expired (code was working fine before).

Code i use to get key-info node:

```
private KeyInfo getKeyInfo()
{
  KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
  KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoX509Data = new KeyInfoX509Data(this.certificate, X509IncludeOption.ExcludeRoot);
  keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoX509Data);
  return keyInfo;
}
```

If you need me to post more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to eliminate the intermediate certificate in your output, change

```
new KeyInfoX509Data(this.certificate, X509IncludeOption.ExcludeRoot);
```

to

```
new KeyInfoX509Data(this.certificate, X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly);
```

Then it will write just the signing cert, instead of the chain (except for the root).

Answer (score 2):

In a XML signature it is expected that includes the signing certificate and the **certification chain** in order the recipient could verify trust until the root CA certificate

See [XMLDsig standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-X509Data)

> *4.4.4 The X509Data Element*
>
> All certificates appearing in an X509Data element MUST relate to the validation key by either containing it or being part of a certification chain that terminates in a certificate containing the validation key.

If the certification chain of your new certificate contains one intermediate certificate until root, it is normal that you see two certificates in X509Data

```
 root
   --intermediate1
       --leaf
```

You can check it opening the certificate with an editor (double click in windows)

Comment: Problem is validation schema does not allow more than one <X509Certificate> tag.

Comment: The standard allows several tags, so i am afraid you have to modify your validation schema. Workaround: choose a new certificate from a CA without intermediates

Comment: The XML i am signing and then validating is issued by our goverment. Schema does not allow it and also when i am trying to validate signed XML on website designed for it i am getting error (validation failed: multiple elements). So the only way here is different certificate?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. An XMLDsig signature supports several X509Certificate elements as you can see in the link that I have passed and in the [validation XSD](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core -schema.xsd # SPKIData). Therefore if the goverment is using a custom validation schema, then they have designed it incorrectly. Could you post a link to the XSD?

Comment: If you remove the intermediate certificate of the signature, then the client won't be able to verify the signature because there will be a missing certificate. If the client includes the intermediate certificate in their trust list then you could omit it from the signature (Doing the same with your XMLDsig signature library). The alternative, as I said, it is using a different certificate

Comment: This is the error message and it includes namespace:The element X509Data in namespace
 http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig# 
 has invalid child element X509Certificate in namespace 
 http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#.; 
 namespace: http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#.

Comment: This does not make sense. See XSD `<complexType name="X509DataType"><sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
<choice>
<element name="X509Certificate" type="base64Binary"/>` X509DataType can contain multiple X509Certificate. I suggest to contact with the server manager

Comment: Ok will do. Thank you for your help.